# jquery form change detection

Tags: jquery

nice script. Can someone please explain to me how to implement it with other form tag like radio and also with file upload.

have Dream Day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code ,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="../jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
              });
          $("div").text(str);
        })
        .change();

  });
  </script>
  <style>
  div { color:red; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Chocolate</option>
    <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
    <option>Taffy</option>
    <option selected="selected">Carmel</option>
    <option>Fudge</option>
    <option>Cookie</option>
  </select>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input").change(function(){
  // do something
});
```

[Click here](http://api.jquery.com/change/) for more information.